# Angular 2 ngModel working only one way?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

My component template form doesn't track initialized form value in **ngOnInit** using **ngModel**. It works fine one way (from template to component.ts) but not the other way.

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. Currently this question is entirely pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. I was using the same name value for two inputs.

Comment: don't care about downvotes, at least this way it can help others facing the same issue

Comment: Well this question and answer doesn't help anyone since it has no context, no code, nothing. Why do you believe you are getting downvotes. If this would be useful, you'd get upvotes, right? :)

Comment: it explains that using two inputs with same name leads to one way binding for angular 2 ngModel